# Custom domain does not work on Heroku app url

Tags: node.js, express, github, heroku, terminal

I am trying to link my heroku app to my domain. 
The image below shows that my heroku is pointing my my domain

https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Dnu7GK_UcAAd7vE.jpg:large

but when you visit my domain

https://cleveroscar.com

it loads up my markdown file instead of my app,

but on my heroku url the app is working perfect

https://young-castle-28382.herokuapp.com/

I am a self-taught developer so please excuse my unprofessional questions

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right way to point your hosting to your domain name
Did you do them?

```
 heroku domains:add example.com

    heroku domains:add www.example.com

    heroku domains:add *.example.com
```

This is to point your domain name from heroku side

Here is a youtube video to make it easier https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKGSGT7mSnQ&t=29s

Please let me know if this does work